# Reset Question number to 1 after a new section

Tags: numbering, templates

in the Template [`Lachaise Assignment`](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/lachaise-assignment)  is possible to create questions. For example

```
\documentclass{article}

\input{structure.tex} % Include the file specifying the document structure and custom commands

\begin{document}


\begin{question}
    Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

    % Subquestions numbered with letters
    \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
        \item Do this.
        \item Do that.
        \item Do something else.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{question}


\begin{question}
    Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

    % Subquestions numbered with letters
    \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
        \item Do this.
        \item Do that.
        \item Do something else.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{question}
    
%------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

[image]

I wish to reset the number of the question in a new \section (not 3), like this

[image]

The questions environment, difinied in structure file, is:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NUMBERED QUESTIONS ENVIRONMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Usage:
% \begin{question}[optional title]
%   Question contents
% \end{question}

\mdfdefinestyle{question}{
    innertopmargin=1.2\baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin=0.8\baselineskip,
    roundcorner=5pt,
    nobreak,
    singleextra={%
        \draw(P-|O)node[xshift=1em,anchor=west,fill=white,draw,rounded corners=5pt]{%
        Question \theQuestion\questionTitle};
    },
}

\newcounter{Question} % Stores the current question number that gets iterated with each new question

% Define a custom environment for numbered questions
\newenvironment{question}[1][\unskip]{
    \bigskip
    \stepcounter{Question}
    \newcommand{\questionTitle}{~#1}
    \begin{mdframed}[style=question]
}{
    \end{mdframed}
    \medskip
}
```

Comment: How is the `question` environment defined?

Comment: It would help if you would include the used packages in the code itself. But: does \setcounter{question}{1} placed immediately af the \section{} work?

Comment: placing the \setcounter{question}{1} placed immediately af the \section{} I got the following error message "! LaTeX Error: No counter 'question' defined."

Comment: @Bernard in the Template Lachaise Assignment there is a structure file

Comment: @Bernard I updated my question

Comment: From the definition of the environment, it seems that you need to manipulate the counter `Question`, like this: `\setcounter{Question}{1}`.

Comment: Thanks, finally It works!

Comment: Great! Credit goes to @C.Peters, if they would like to write an answer!

Comment: You also can add in your preamble `\counterwithin*{Question}{section}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this as an answer instead of a comment for visibility.

For heaven's sake, don't do things like reset the counter manually with every section by doing a `\setcounter` after every `\section` command. This is really bad form.

The correct way to manage this is, as Bernard mentioned in his comment,¹ is to write

```
\counterwithin*{Question}{section}
```

The \verb+*+ there is to not redefine `\theQuestion` to include the section number. Without it, your questions would be numbered 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, etc.

I'd also note that the `question` environment has

```
\stepcounter{Question}
```

in its definition. I would recommend changing that to `\refstepcounter{Question}` to allow references to questions by number.²

Of course, since we are numbering within sections, there's a problem with being able to distinguish question 1 in section 1 from question 1 in section 2. Fortunately, \LaTeX\ provides a mechanism to allow this. We need to define `\p@`*countername* for a prefix to the counter that will appear in references only. The `@` indicates that its a private command so we'll need to have this definition in a class/package file or else put it inside `\makeatletter`…`\makeatother`:³

```
\makeatletter
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\p@Question}{}{\thesection.}
\makeatother
```

If your LaTeX is out of date you may need to write instead

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\p@Question}{\thesection.}
\makeatother
```

Then we'll get 1.1 for a `\ref` to the first question in section 1 and 2.1 for a `\ref` to the first question in section 2. Really clever TeX hackers can use the `\p@` mechanism to do things like completely change the formatting of a reference's output, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

---

1. Speaking of bad form, there are way too many questions on this site that get answered in comments instead of in answers, often with the correct answer only showing up in a comment which might get hidden thanks to the way that stackexchange selectively shows comments.
2. Also, there's no reason for the counter to have been named `Question` instead of `question`. Counters live in a separate namespace from environments and commands so there's no problem having a counter with the same name as an environment and a lot of incentive to, in fact, have the counter use the same name as its associated environment.
3. We have to use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` instead of `\NewDocumentCommand` so that the correct value will be stored in the reference.